# Python: Convert numpy array of ones complement integers to twos complement integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program which produces a csv output. The program is written in C and writes lines to the csv file using something very similar to this line of code:

```
uint16_t value = 0x8001; // this means -1 if MSB = sign bit
fprintf(fout, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", (int)value, ... some other stuff here);
```

I cannot easily change this line of code, as I have already collected the data using the compiled C executable, and I cannot easily re-run the thing which generates the data.

I started reading in the csv file using the following python code:

```
 11 def plot(filename):
 12 
 13     with open(filename, "r") as f:
 14 
 15         csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
 16         next(csvreader) # skip head
 17         data_in = list(csvreader)
 18 
 19         data_matrix = numpy.array(data_in, dtype=numpy.int)
 20         
 23         data_x          = data_matrix[:, 2]
 24         data_y          = data_matrix[:, 3]
 25         data_z          = data_matrix[:, 4]
```

However at this point I noticed the data was likely encoded with a sign bit.

Can I do something in my python code to convert an integer to an integer treating the MSB as a sign bit?

Some possible ideas include:

- Some kind of iteration over the data like below, and checking if the value is > 2**15, if so, multiply by -1 or subtract the value 2 ** 16, element by element

  data = [some operation on x for x in data: do something] # not really sure about this
- Some kind of conversion function already contained in python? (No idea what this would be)
- Converting from integer type to some fixed width type and performing some kind of bit hack or converting back to integer again, taking into account MSB as sign bit

The above are all just initial ideas, and I don't really know how I would express any of them in Python.

Comment: Write a function that represents the conversion, and then [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) it over the array?

Comment: Can you include an example of an initialized `data_matrix`? That lets answers post working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, the first bulletpoint can be achieved:

```
data_out = [x - 2**16 if x > 2**15 else x for x in data_in]
```

There may be better ways to do this, but this is one solution which works.